When compressing from a HEVC source, is H264 a better choice than H265 if I want to minimize information loss?
If a video source is 2160p HEVC and I wish to compress it to 1080p, will information loss be lesser if I compress it to H264 instead of H265?

Note that either codec may be used for either resolution.

No.
H.265 (a.k.a. HEVC) has better quality at the same bitrate when compared to H.264 (a.k.a. AVC). But you might want to convert to H.264 for wider compatibility.
